# Maximum sub-arrays that an array can be divided into such that GCD of any two elements in different sub-arrays is always 1?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

Given `n`, the number of array elements and `arr[n]`, the array of numbers, it is required to find the maximum number of sub-arrays the array can be divided into such that `GCD(a,b)=1` for every `a` and `b` that belong to different sub-arrays.

Eg:

```
5
2 3 4 5 6
Ans: 2 ----> {(2,3,4,6),(5)}
```

Every other attempt to divide it further will not satisfy the conditions.

**My Approach:**
1. Sort the array.
2. Keep calculating the `lcm`of the elements.
3. Increase the counter every time the `gcd` of the element and `lcm` of elements before is `1`.

```
int main()
{
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        long long int arr[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
            cin>>arr[i];
        sort(arr,arr+n);
        long long int ans=1,l=arr[n-1];
        for(int i=n-2;i>=0;i--)
        {
            if(gcd(l,arr[i])==1)
                ans++;
            l=lcm(l,arr[i]);
        }
        cout<<ans<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

After my answer being judged `wrong answer` multiple times, I am confused whether my solution is correct. Since the limit for `n` was `10^6` and array element was `10^7`, another reason the solution would have failed is that the `LCM` can exceed the `long long` limit. Is there any other solution possible? Or is there any mistake in the present approach?

Comment: Are you referring to this problem: https://www.codechef.com/problems/CHEFGRUP

Because the constrains stated that 2 <= A[i] <= 10^7, but you have `1` in the array.

Comment: @Shubham .. yes its the same....and I just gave an example ... edited!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the problem you are referring to: https://www.codechef.com/problems/CHEFGRUP

My approach is as follows **(I got Time Limit Exceeded)**:

### Step - 1: Calculate all the primes in the range [1, 10^7].

This can be done using Sieve of Eratosthenes and the complexity will be `O(nlog(log(n))` where n can be upto `10^7`.

### Step - 2: Use the vector of primes calculated above to find prime factorization of all the numbers in the array.

This can be implemented very efficiently once we have all the required primes.

The point to note in this step is that, suppose we have 2 numbers whose prime factorization contains common prime numbers, then these two elements cannot be in different subarrays because then GCD won't be 1 (as required in the question). Hence, for all such pairs, they will have to be in the same subarray. How to achieve this?

### Step - 3: Use Disjoint Set Data Structure.

We can create a disjoint set of all the prime numbers. So the number of sets in the beginning will be the number of prime numbers. Then, during each factorization, we will join all the prime numbers that is a divisor and add them all in the same group with the original number. This will be repeated for all the numbers.

Also, we will have to check once, whether some prime numbers was even required in the first place. Because before this step we just assumed that there are as many sets as the prime numbers in the range. But some might be unused. So, this can be checked by traversing a loop once and finding the number of unique representatives. This will be our answer.

My code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long int ll;

int prime[(int)1e7+10] = {0};

struct union_find {
    std::vector <int> parent, rank;

    // Constructor to initialse 'parent' and 'rank' vector.
    union_find(int n) {
        parent = std::vector <int> (n);
        rank = std::vector <int> (n, 0);        // initialse rank vector with 0.
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            parent[i] = i;
    }

    // Find with Path Compression Heuristic.
    int find_(int a) {
        if(a == parent[a])
            return a;
        return parent[a] = find_(parent[a]);
    }

    // Union by checking rank to keep the depth of the tree as shallow as possible.
    void union_(int a, int b) {
        int aa = find_(a), bb = find_(b);
        if(rank[aa] < rank[bb])
            parent[aa] = bb;
        else
            parent[bb] = aa;
        if(rank[aa] == rank[bb])
            ++rank[aa];
    }
};

union_find ds(1e7+10);

int main() {
    int n;
    int sq = sqrt(1e7+10);
    for(int i = 4; i < 1e7+10; i += 2)
        prime[i] = 1;
    for(int i = 3; i <= sq; i += 2) {
        if(!prime[i]) {
            for(int j = i*i; j < 1e7+10; j += i)
                prime[j] = 1;
        }
    }

    vector <int> primes;
    primes.push_back(2);
    for(int i = 3; i < 1e7+10; i += 2) {
        if(!prime[i])
            primes.push_back(i);
    }


    scanf("%d", &n);
    int a[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        int temp = a[i];
        // int sq = sqrt(temp);
        vector <int> divisors;
        for(int j = 0; j < primes.size(); j++) {
            if(primes[j] > temp)
                break;
            if(temp % primes[j] == 0) {
                divisors.push_back(primes[j]);
                while(temp % primes[j] == 0) {
                    temp /= primes[j];
                }
            }
        }
        if(temp > 2)
            divisors.push_back(temp);

        for(int i = 1; i < divisors.size(); i++)
            ds.union_(divisors[i], divisors[i-1]);
        if(divisors.size() > 0)
            ds.union_(divisors[0], a[i]);
    }

    set <int> unique;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int x = ds.find_(a[i]);
        unique.insert(x);
    }

    printf("%d\n", unique.size());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: factorization and union_find is a pretty good approach, but to factor numbers <= 10^7, you only need primes <= 3137, since to factor a number N you only need to check divisors <= sqrt(N)